# Llamar a un method dentro de otro

Tags: java

Antes que nada disculpas si la consulta es muy sencilla pero estoy comenzando a programar en Java y no se si comprendo lo que está sucediendo.

He logrado programar un sencillo conversor de km/h a millas/h y si bien he logrado que funcione me gustaría entender si lo que ocurre al invocar el method printConversion es lo siguiente:

- pasa 10.5 al method printConversion
- como kilometersPerHour (10.5) no es < 0, pasa a crear la variable milesPerHour
- la nueva variable milesPerHour llama al method toMilesPerHour y le pasa kilometersPerHour (10.5)
- se hace la division/conversion dentro del method toMilesPerHour y se le asigna a la variable recién creada milesPerHour
- se hace print out

---

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printConversion(10.5);
    }

    public static long toMilesPerHour(double kilometersPerHour){
        if (kilometersPerHour < 0){
            return -1;
        }

        return Math.round(kilometersPerHour / 1.609); //lo divide y lo redondea. devuelve 7, valor en MILLAS
    }

    public static void printConversion(double kilometersPerHour){
        if (kilometersPerHour < 0){
            System.out.println("Invalid Value");
        } else {
            long milesPerHour = toMilesPerHour(kilometersPerHour); //QUE PASA EN ESTA LINEA?
            System.out.println(kilometersPerHour + " km/h = " + milesPerHour + " mi/h");
        }
    }
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Exactamente lo que decis.. pero milesPerHour no llama a toMilesPerHour. Esa funcion es llamada y su resultado se guarda en milesPerHour.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Saludos.

Comment: Tene en cuenta que la pregunta mas alla del comentario, no tiene mucho sentido. podrias borrarla?

Answer (score -1):

Solo tienes que seguir el flujo del código.

1. Primero todo empieza con el método main. Dentro del método main se manda a llamar el método printConversion(10.5);
2. El método printConversion recibe el numero 10.5 en su variable kilometersPerHour y se evalúa el if. Como la condición del if no es satisfactoria se ejecuta el else. Dentro del else se manda a llamar el metodo toMilesPerHour(kilometersPerHour); Donde kilometersPerHour es 10.5.
3. El método toMilesPerHour recibe el numero 10.5 en su variable kilometersPerHour, no entra en el if y se ejecuta el return; es decir que se ejecuta la instrucción de Math.round(kilometersPerHour / 1.609) y el valor es retornado por el método.
4. Regresamos resultado del método toMilesPerHour a la variable long milesPerHour del método printConversion y por ultimo se ejecuta del print a la consola.

Espero haya sido claro.